# Investigating cowboy / cowlib / ranch exceptions in phoenix app

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, cowboy

I have a phoenix app that keeps raising multiple different exceptions in production. I'm trying to investigate the exceptions but I'm not sure if my endpoint configuration is wrong, are these bugs in the dependencies? Are the issues somehow related? Which dependency is responsible for them?

I don't want to open tickets and start a ping-pong conversation between different projects so I thought about asking here first.

#### dependencies

- cowboy: 1.0.4
- cowlib: 1.0.2
- ranch: 1.2.1
- phoenix: 1.2

#### The exceptions

1)

```
17:58:21.973 [error] Ranch protocol #PID<0.8216.13> (:cowboy_protocol) of listener Krihelinator.Endpoint.HTTP terminated
** (exit) an exception was raised:
   ** (FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching in :cowboy_protocol.parse_method/3
        (cowboy) src/cowboy_protocol.erl:168: :cowboy_protocol.parse_method("", {:state, #Port<0.19168>, :ranch_tcp, [:cowboy_router, :cowboy_handler], true, [listener: Krihelinator.Endpoint.HTTP, dispatch: [{:_, [], [{["socket", "websocket"], [], Phoenix.Endpoint.CowboyWebSocket, {Phoenix.Transports.WebSocket, {Krihelinator.Endpoint, Krihelinator.UserSocket, :websocket}}}, {:_, [], Plug.Adapters.Cowboy.Handler, {Krihelinator.Endpoint, []}}]}]], :undefined, :undefined, 5, 1, 100, 4096, 64, 4096, 100, 5000, 1490810306970}, <<0, 0, 0, 113, 106, 129, 110, 48, 129, 107, 161, 3, 2, 1, 5, 162, 3, 2, 1, 10, 164, 129, 94, 48, 92, 160, 7, 3, 5, 0, 80, 128, 0, 16, 162, 4, 27, 2, 78, 77, 163, 23, 48, 21, 160, 3, 2, 1, 0, 161, ...>>)
```

2)

```
2017-04-06 06:21:14.693 [error] Ranch protocol #PID<0.21785.1> (:cowboy_protocol) of listener Krihelinator.Endpoint.HTTP terminated
** (exit) an exception was raised:
    ** (FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching in :cowboy_protocol.parse_uri_path/4
        (cowboy) src/cowboy_protocol.erl:200: :cowboy_protocol.parse_uri_path("", {:state, #Port<0.6072>, :ranch_tcp, [:cowboy_router, :cowboy_handler], true, [listener: Krihelinator.Endpoint.HTTP, dispatch: [{:_, [], [{["socket", "websocket"], [], Phoenix.Endpoint.CowboyWebSocket, {Phoenix.Transports.WebSocket, {Krihelinator.Endpoint, Krihelinator.UserSocket, :websocket}}}, {:_, [], Plug.Adapters.Cowboy.Handler, {Krihelinator.Endpoint, []}}]}]], :undefined, :undefined, 5, 1, 100, 4096, 64, 4096, 100, 5000, 1491459679639}, <<71, 104, 48, 115, 116, 173, 0, 0, 0, 224, 0, 0, 0, 120, 156, 75, 83, 96, 96, 152, 195, 192, 192, 192, 6, 196, 140, 64, 188, 81, 150, 129, 129, 9, 72, 7, 167, 22, 149, 101, 38, 167, 42, 4, 36, 38, 103, 43, 24, 50, ...>>, <<2, 0, 84, 245, 43, 92>>)
```

3)

```
18:20:18.395 [error] Ranch protocol #PID<0.28926.18> (:cowboy_protocol) of listener Krihelinator.Endpoint.HTTP terminated
** (exit) an exception was raised:
    ** (FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching in :cow_http_hd.token_ci_list_sep/3
        (cowlib) src/cow_http_hd.erl:191: :cow_http_hd.token_ci_list_sep("Te", [], "keep-alive")
        (cowlib) src/cow_http_hd.erl:31: :cow_http_hd.parse_connection/1
        (cowboy) src/cowboy_req.erl:189: :cowboy_req.new/14
        (cowboy) src/cowboy_protocol.erl:410: :cowboy_protocol.request/9
```

As you can see, I have no clue why the issues happen. So maybe I didn't provided enough information. Please ask for for more if needed.
Any guidance to help me fix these or open ticket(s) to the correct project will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The client is sending an invalid keepalive header and cowboy is very strict on that, see https://github.com/ninenines/cowboy/issues/943

If you know the client you could ask for a fix, or rewrite the header in a proxy, e.g. haproxy

```
  # cowboy crashes when invalid headers are sent
  # see https://github.com/ninenines/cowboy/issues/943
  acl invalid_keepalive_header hdr(Connection) -i keep-alive\ Te
  reqirep ^Connection:\ keep-alive\ Te  Connection:\ keep-alive,\ Te if invalid_keepalive_header

  acl invalid_keepalive_header_1 hdr(Connection) -i Te\ keep-alive
  reqirep ^Connection:\ Te\ keep-alive  Connection:\ keep-alive,\ Te if invalid_keepalive_header_1
```